# Parse.com: stop background job at 14 minutes

Tags: background, parse-platform

How can I stop a background job at 14 minutes or after?

I basically have sub queries that can last 15 seconds Max and I'd like to stop them at 14m 15sec maximum so I can make sure they all completely terminate. I don't know how to implement a timer on a background job

Comment: I thought you need to queue up your jobs and check the time left before execute the job.

Comment: how do I check the time left in javascript?
the idea would be
job{ startTimer(); Loop (if getTimer <14minutes do cloudcode else break); }. Can't go further than the pseudocode

Comment: Yes, you need to set a start time before executing any jobs. Then use (new now time - start time) to get how long you have performed and only executing the next job if the time is smaller than the maximum run time.

Comment: Awesome! What's the code snippet for achieving to time now in parse?

Comment: try `Date.now()` or `new Date().getTime()`